# How to perform such an aggregation in BigQuery[multiple columns of type array]

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery, aggregate

So far I have managed to aggregate the value for one column:

```
with test_data as (
  select '2024-02-26 10:00:00' added,'2024-02-26 10:15:00' finished,[1,2,3,4] array1,[2,4,2,3] array2,'testname1' name
  union all
  select '2024-02-26 10:30:00' added,'2024-02-26 10:45:00' finished,[4,4,6,3] array1,[4,5,7,9] array2,'testname1' name
  union all 
  select '2024-02-26 10:45:00' added,'2024-02-26 11:00:00' finished,[2,4,5,2] array1,[8,7,4,3] array2,'testname1' name
  union all
  select '2024-02-26 10:00:00' added,'2024-02-26 10:15:00' finished,[2,3,1,1] array1,[2,1,1,3] array2,'testname2' name
  union all
  select '2024-02-26 10:30:00' added,'2024-02-26 10:45:00' finished,[6,6,6,6] array1,[2,1,1,3] array2,'testname2' name
  union all
  select '2024-02-26 10:45:00' added,'2024-02-26 11:00:00' finished,[2,4,7,6] array1,[3,2,5,3] array2,'testname2' name
) 

SELECT CAST(MIN(added) AS TIMESTAMP) AS added, CAST(MAX(finished) AS TIMESTAMP) AS finished,name,ARRAY_AGG(array1 ORDER BY idx) as array1, ([14,16,13,15]) as array2 FROM (SELECT CAST(MIN(added) AS TIMESTAMP) AS added, CAST(MAX(finished) AS TIMESTAMP) AS finished,name,idx,SUM(array1) AS array1 FROM test_data, UNNEST(array1) AS array1 WITH OFFSET idx where added >= "2024-02-26 10:00:00" AND finished <= "2024-02-26 11:00:00" GROUP BY idx,name) GROUP BY name
```

how to do such a thing for two and more columns or is it possible to do this in bq?

I would like to achieve this result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXqnA.png)

json result:

```
[{
  "added": "2024-02-26 10:00:00.000000 UTC",
  "finished": "2024-02-26 11:00:00.000000 UTC",
  "name": "testname1",
  "array1": ["7", "10", "14", "9"],
  "array2": ["14", "16", "13", "15"]
}, {
  "added": "2024-02-26 10:00:00.000000 UTC",
  "finished": "2024-02-26 11:00:00.000000 UTC",
  "name": "testname2",
  "array1": ["10", "13", "14", "13"],
  "array2": ["7", "4", "7", "9"]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your arrays always have four positions, you could just first access individual indexes, then do a simple group by with a `SUM`, and then compose back the results as an array. I don't have access to bigquery right now, but tried on a different database this query and worked. Hopefully it should work with little or no changes for you. Note that I replaced the column `name` by `xname` as it was a reserved keyword on my database.

```sql
with flat_table as (
  select xname, 
  added, 
  finished, 
  array1[0] a10, array1[1] a11, array1[2] a12, array1[3] a13, 
  array2[0] a20, array2[1] a21, array2[2] a22, array2[3] a23  
  from test_data
) 
select xname, 
       min(added), 
       max(finished), 
       [sum(a10), sum(a11), sum(a12), sum(a13)] array1,  
       [sum(a20), sum(a21), sum(a22), sum(a23)] array2 
from flat_table 
group by xname;

As you can see, results are identical to yours.
[![Results on a table][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZLEo.png
```

Comment: Thank you Javier, I have checked your solution works well in bigquery. If the size of the array is not always the same or is different for the array do you think there is a way to make it work too?

Comment: If memory serves me well, you could do a join between the parent table and the unnest from the child in bigquery, so I guess the trick there would be joining each array with index, then grouping by idx as you were doing, but I cannot test that myself since it's been years since I've used bigquery :(

Comment: Thx Javier, I have also thought about maybe this solution: `SELECT added,finished,name,
  ARRAY(SELECT
          (SELECT SUM(array1[OFFSET(off)]) FROM UNNEST(all_array))
        FROM UNNEST(all_array[OFFSET(0)].array1) WITH OFFSET off),   
  ARRAY(SELECT
          (SELECT SUM(array2[OFFSET(off)]) FROM UNNEST(all_array))
        FROM UNNEST(all_array[OFFSET(0)].array2) WITH OFFSET off)
FROM (
  SELECT
    CAST(MIN(added) AS TIMESTAMP) AS added, CAST(MAX(finished) AS TIMESTAMP) AS finished,name,ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(array1,array2)) AS all_array
  FROM test_data GROUP BY name
)`

Comment: and I forgot to use SAFE_OFFSET(off) instead of OFFSET(off) and to use SAFE_OFFSET(0) instead of OFFSET(0)